# Django managed=False model save doing insert instead of update and failing for duplicate PK

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

I'm connected to a legacy database using PyODBC. Some models insert and update just fine, however this one doesn't. When we grab existing records using the ORM, it tries to do an insert on save instead of an update

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    purchaseorderid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='PurchaseOrderId', primary_key=True)
    ticketnumber = models.CharField(db_column='TicketNumber', unique=True, max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', to_field='local_id', db_column='CustId', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    # a bunch of other irrelevant columns
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PurchaseOrders'
```

In the shell (or code anywhere else) I can grab an existing PurchaseOrder and even print it's pk just fine:

```
>>> po = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()[76543]  # grab a random existing po
>>> print(po.pk)
78730
```

But when I go to save the record, which should do an update -- we've verified the pk exists -- it tries to do an insert and fails due to duplicate pk:

```
>>> po.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 621, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PurchaseOrders_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PurchaseOrders'. The duplicate key value is (78730). (2627) (SQLExecDirectW)")

If I change the model to use an integer field instead of autofield, it again tries to insert instead of updating and fails:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    purchaseorderid = models.IntegerField(db_column='PurchaseOrderId', primary_key=True) 


>>> po = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()[74563]
>>> print(po.pk)
76703
>>> po.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in     _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 621, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL     Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PurchaseOrders' when     IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
self.save_base(
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in     save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in     _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in      _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in     _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line     1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102,     in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in     execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in    _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in    _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in     _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/django/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 621, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]    [SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PurchaseOrders' when     IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Anyone have an idea why Django is choking and trying to insert when the record has a clearly defined pk? We're grabbing the record straight from the ORM, so why does it think it's a new record?

Answer (score 0):

Since `managed=False` is set for the `PurchaseOrder` model. I am assuming that you created this model by some other means (example: manually created using SQL DDL statements in the database). If thats the case, the field `purchaseorderid` may not have the primary key in the database. There might be another field in the database which is the primary key.

Easy way to debug this is to `print(p.pk)` and `print(p.purchaseorderid)` and compare both.

Or you can use a database viewer tool such as Dbeaver and look into the state of the database and verify.

Comment: It's a table from a legacy DB. Messing around with things apparently some of the redacted columns matter - (though ticketnumber causes the same problem). I decided to alter mssql/base.py to print out the queries it executes -- and to my surprise this save is causing not ONE but TWO queries to fire -- an update query that actually succeeds followed by an insert query that does not.

Comment: Are you able to see into the database using some tool such as Dbeaver?